# How to extract the URL from xml or any text file

Tags: sed, grep, xml

My XML file;

```
<settings version="2">
    <setting id="TimeShift" default="true">0</setting>
    <setting id="Override" default="true">false</setting>
    <setting id="Cache">true</setting>
    <setting id="Path">/storage/</setting>
    <setting id="PathType">0</setting>
    <setting id="Url1">http://localhost:8080/main.php?value1=abcd-1234&value2=OqUy1cHm&type=post</setting>
    <setting id="startNum">1</setting>
</settings>
```

I need to extract the variable URL value. I tried some sed and grep commands but don't get result. Which command should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the URL is actually encoded properly (it isn't now, which would break some XML parsers; both `&` should be `&amp;`):

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/settings/setting[@id = "Url1"]' -nl file.xml
http://localhost:8080/main.php?value1=abcd-1234&amp;value2=OqUy1cHm&amp;type=post
```

This uses `xmlstarlet` to fetch the value for the `/settings/setting` document node whose `id` attribute is `Url1`.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable information. You are right for (&) character. I did a manual copy-paste of the url for the example.